# Optimizing SQL Cross Join that checks if any array value in other column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, cross-join

Let's say I have a table `events` with structure:

| id | value_array |
| --- | --- |
| XXXX | [a,b,c,d] |
| ... | ... |

I have a second table `values_of_interest` with structure:

| value |
| --- |
| x |
| y |
| z |
| a |

I want to find id's that have any of the values found in `values_of_interest`. All else equal, what would be the most performant SQL to make this happen? (I am using BigQuery, but feel free to answer more generally)

My current thought is:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT e.id 
FROM 
  events e, values_of_interest vi 
WHERE 
  EXISTS(
     SELECT 
       value 
     FROM
       UNNEST(e.value_array) value 
     JOIN 
       vi ON vi.value = e.value 
        )
```

Comment: No, put `values_of_interest` on the inside of the subquery, followed by `unnest`. Aside: you really shouldn't use `,` as a join, it's been deprecated for many years already.

Answer (score 1):

Few quick options for BigQuery Standard SQL

Option 1

```
select id
from `project.dataset.events`
where exists (
  select 1
  from `project.dataset.values_of_interest` 
  where value in unnest(value_array)
)
```

Option 2

```
select id
from `project.dataset.events` t
where (
  select count(1)
  from t.value_array as value
  join `project.dataset.values_of_interest`
  using(value)
) > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write this using `exists` and a `join`:

```
select e.id
from `project.dataset.events` e
where exists (select 1
              from unnest(e.value_array) val join
                   `project.dataset.values_of_interest` voi
                   on val = voi.value
             );
```